# R package equivalent to Matlab's Bayes net toolbox for network structure learning using time data

Tags: r, time, bayesian

I'm doing a study on time series data of protein phosphorylation events, and I want to use dynamic bayesian network to learn the network structure. I found your Bayes net toolbox can be helpful for my study.But I'm more familiar with R. Is there any R packages equivalent to Matlab's Bayes net toolbox, which can learn the network structure using time series data? Thank you!

Comment: By default it surely qualifies for *"asking to recommend a tool"*, but I do have to say that it did help me a lot. This question should remain here, maybe an edit could help keep it alive.

Answer (score 3):

try the following R packages to perform dynamic bayesian networks inference:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/G1DBN/index.html

and

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ebdbNet/index.html

enjoy!